# Highlight intersection between two primitives objects from shader code in webgl

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am looking for a way to highlight the intersection of two primitives, more specifically 2 cylinders, directly from the fragment shader code. 

I'm using THREE.js and adding 2 meshes with ShaderMaterial, the second one I would like to pass the position and the top radius (= bottom radius) of the first one as uniforms, and if they intersect, color the intersection area differently. 

Also need to mention that I don't want to use CSG.
I've just started to learn glsl and 3d. Thanks!

Comment: have a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828434/displaying-only-overlapping-parts)

Comment: No no, I don't want to use CSG. I'm trying to do this to get rid of it actually.

Comment: This really isn't something you'd use a fragment shader for, to be honest. The stencil buffer was created for this sort of thing, and up until very recently you could not read the stencil buffer from a fragment shader (you still can't in WebGL).

Answer (score 0):

How about rendering object or material IDs to a texture and running some edge detection method on it, similarly to non-photorealistic rendering (some links below)?

After rendering to your texture, draw a full screen polygon in which the fragment shader reads from the texture. In addition to the colour at the fragment position, grab values around it. If any of the colours in the surrounding pixels are different, you know the fragment is near an intersection and can colour it whatever you like. If not, discard.

[image: Celshading_teapot_large]

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator
- http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall00/cs597b/papers/saito90.pdf
- http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter15.html
- https://hpi.de/fileadmin/user_upload/hpi/navigation/10_forschung/30_publikationen/15_dissertationen/Diss_Nienhaus.pdf